# Searching for area code in txt-file in Python

Tags: python, search, text-files

I have a textfile that looks like this:

```
Thomas Edgarson, Berliner Str 4, 13359 Berlin
Madeleine Jones, Müller Str 5, 15992 Karlsruhe
etc...
```

It's always two words, followed by a comma, then two words and number, comma, area code and city. There are no exceptions.

I used

```
f=open("C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\Desktop\\useradresses.txt", "r")
text=f.readlines()
f.close()
```

So now I have a list of all the columns. How can I now search for the area codes in these strings. I need to create a dictionary that looks like this

```
{'13359':[('Neuss','Wolfgang'),('Juhnke','Harald')]}
```

Believe me, I've searched, but couldn't find useful information. To me, the whole idea of searching for something like an arbitray area code in a string is new and I haven't come across it so far.

I would be happy if you could give me some pointers as to where I should look for tutorials or give me an idea where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dic = {}
with open('filename') as file:
    for name, addr, zcode in (i.split(',') for i in file if i.rstrip()):
        dic.setdefault(zcode.split()[0], []).append(name.split())
```

Further explanation as Sjoerd asked:

Using a generator expression to break each line in 3 variables: name, addr and zcode. Then I split zcode in the desired number and used it as a dictionary key.

As the dict may not have the key yet, I use the `setdefault` method and that sets the key with a empty list before appending the splitted name.

Comment: Nice code, but since this is homework and a simple assignment the poster is not likely to understand what exactly you are doing here. Also, his teacher will see immediately that he has been cheating if he hands this in.

Comment: Thank you, i am intrigued by your answer, but I think it is a little below my current level as a python programmer ;). But I will try it out nonetheless, to see what it does.

Comment: Why do you use setdefault in each iteration instead of once at the beginning of the code?

Answer (score 1):

[Loop](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/File/Loopthroughafile.htm) through the file, reading lines, and [split](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/string-methods.html#l2h-262) by comma. Then, process each part by splitting by space. Then, add the values to a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I didn't stumble upon the concept of **seperators** or **split** yet, so this was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
d={}

for line in open('useradresses.txt','r'):
    if line.strip()=='':
        continue
    (name,strasse,plzort) = line.split(',')
    nachname,vorname=name.split()
    plz,ort=plzort.split()
    if plz in d:
        d[plz].append((nachname,vorname))
    else:
        d[plz]=[(nachname,vorname),]
print d
```

Answer (score -1):

Python has a lot of libraries dealing with string manipulation, which is what this is. You'll be wanting the [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) library and the [shlex](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html) library. I'd suggest the following code:

```py
with open("C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\Desktop\\useradresses.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        split = shlex.split(line)
        mydict[split[6]] = [(split[0], split[1])]
```

This won't be perfect, it will overwrite identical zip codes, and drops some values. It should point you in the right direction though.

Comment: The shlex class makes it easy to write lexical analyzers for simple syntaxes resembling that of the Unix shell. The list of addresses in the question is not such a thing.